# Why is my app not the first in the list when I search?

Tags: app-store

This may be a very amateur question so I apologize if the answer is obvious.  I just released my very first app to the App store.  It is called "BlueSucker."  But for some reason it is probably around the 100th app on the list when I search for that name exactly (I didn't actually count but it felt like an eternity scrolling through the list).  But when I search "blue sucker" with a space in between it shows up as the first.  I don't think there is any other app called BlueSucker as far as I can tell.  Why is it not showing up as the first item on the list when the name matches exactly?  And what can I do to optimize the search?

Comment: Google "what can I do to optimize app store search"

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I actually already tried that initially but I think what I would really like to know is if there is something wrong here.  My intuition tells me that it should be the first thing to pop up since the name matches exactly.  But since it doesn't, I'm wondering if this is to be expected and I need to try to use search optimization techniques as well as try to make my game more popular, or if this is actually just an error on the part of apple or perhaps something that I did wrong when submitting the app.

Answer (score 0):

The AppStore-search works the following:

- if you type two words with space between (like "my app") it will give you the same result as it would if you typed the words separately
- if you search for the name including a "-" it will do the same as above
- searching for the two words (like "myapp" instead of "my app" or "my-app") it should show your app first (or as one of the first) even if the actual name includes a " " or "-"

Hope that helps your understanding :)